# How to use Neovim `sockconnect`?

Tags: neovim, lua, plugin

I want to write a plugin that start 2 child processes. let's say the main nvim process is P, parent. and two child processes are A and B.

In process A, I will do some calculation and write data to process B. The calculation is heavy so I want to use another process so make it async and performant.

Now I am going to follow these steps:

1. in P process, create a pipe via `serverstart`, then I got the pipe address from function returned value. let's say the address is ADDRESS.
2. write 2 lua scripts, let's say they are SA and SB (script for process A, and script for process B).
3. start 2 processes via `jobstart('nvim -l SA ADDRESS')` and `jobstart('nvim -l SB ADDRESS')`. you can see I start two lua scripts and pass them the same pipe address.
4. in SA, it will connect the pipe channel via `sockconnect('pipe', ADDRESS)`, get the channel id, let's say it's ID1. do the calculation, send data via `chansend(ID1, data)`.
5. in sb, it will also connect the pipe channel via `sockconnect('pipe', ADDRESS, {on_data=callback})`, so once there is any data received, it read and consumes them.

But I have some questions:

1. is pipe channel only available for parent-child process data transfer? or it can be used between two child processes from the same parent?

please also give any comments.